# Groupby, transpose each group and multiply by the original group in pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am using Python pandas to do the following. I have a dataframe with F columns and r rows. All fields in this dataframe are numeric. One column denotes the group that each row belongs to. e.g.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': [1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
            'A': [1.5, 0.5, 2.5, 0.5, 1.5, 0.5, 1.5, 0.5],
            'B': [3.5, 2.5, 3.5, 2.5, 3.5, 2.5, 3.5, 2.5]})
```

For each group I need to:

1. Find the mean of each column in this group and subtract the mean from each element

```
normalised_df = df.groupby(['group'], group_keys=True, axis=0).apply(lambda x: x - np.mean(x))

     group         A         B
0        1 -0.333333  0.000000
1        2  0.000000  0.000000
2        1  0.666667  0.000000
3        0 -0.333333 -0.333333
4        0  0.666667  0.666667
5        0 -0.333333 -0.333333
6        1 -0.333333  0.000000
7        2  0.000000  0.000000
```

2. Transpose each group and multiply it by itself (such that I get a matrix with dimensions FxF for each group)

e.g., Group 0:

```
Group 0 transposed:
[-0.333333 0.666667 -0.333333
-0.333333 0.666667 -0.333333]

multiplied by itself:
[-0.333333 -0.333333
 0.666667  0.666667
-0.333333 -0.333333]

to give a 2x2 matrix

[0.666 0.666
 0.666 0.666]
```

3. Add all the FxF matrix from each group together to one.

For step 2, I have tried
`transposed_df = df.groupby(['group']).apply(lambda x: np.transpose(x)*x)`
which errors because the shapes are not aligned (as expected).

The expected outcome would be a matrix of size F by F. It can be a numpy matrix (as this would be more suitable rather than a dataframe). Using the above numbers as example, it would be

```
[1.3333 0.6666
    0.6666 0.6666]
```

Any suggestions as to how to perform this operation?

Comment: can you add the final expected dataframe?

Comment: @anky_91 i've added the expected outcome. I believe a numpy matrix would be better suited than a dataframe, but i'm not wedded to it, if you have a better suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want matrix multiplication is possible use `@` operator and last `sum` per second level of `MultiIndex`:

```
def f(x):
    y = x - np.mean(x)
    return y.T @ y #or y.T.dot(y)

df1 = df.groupby('group')['A','B'].apply(f).sum(level=1)
print (df1)
          A         B
A  1.333333  0.666667
B  0.666667  0.666667
```

Comment: Very elegant! How do I then sum together the three groups to get a single 2x2 matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose a dataframe with df.T

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html

You can dot product a dataframe with another using df.dot

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html

You can matrix multiply (elementwise) a dataframe with another using df.mul

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html

Comment: how do i combine the above with groupby? the operations i would like to perform are per group.

Comment: select each group out into a new df and apply separately